# Can't access collection inside document with rules in firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to get in my application a set of documents inside a collection like this:

```
const plans = await firebase.firestore()
                        .collection('users')
                        .doc(userId)
                        .collection('plans')
                        .get();
```

My firestore rules are set like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow get: if request.auth.uid == userId;

      match /plans/{document=**}  {
        allow create, get, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Every time I try to query all documents in plans collection, I receive this error

```
FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions
```

But if I try to query just the user doc

```
firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(userId).get()
```

It works just fine. I've been stuck on this for a while. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're only allowing `get` for plans.  `get` only allows individual document access.  But a query that returns multiple documents requires `list` access (or `read`, which is both `get` and `list` combined).

Note that `write` is also a combination of `create`, `update`, and `delete`, so you can be more succinct like this:

```
      match /plans/{document=**}  {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      }
```

Read more about [granular operations in the documentation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations)